# How to display latest 4 images from mounted network folder in php?

Tags: php

I have used symlinks to  fetch  mounted network folder in the specified path "/var/www/Access/images".As the beginner tried certain piece of code but it is displaying broken image.I think there is issue in path format,but unable to figure out.Please any one suggest.

```
`<?php
  // Open the directory
  $dir = opendir('/var/www/Access/images');
  // Initialize an array to store the file names and last modified times
  $files = array();

  // Read the contents of the directory
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    // Exclude the current and parent directories
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

    // Check if the file is a directory
    if (is_dir("/var/www/Access/images/'$file")) continue;

    // Get the last modified time for the file
    $lastModified = filemtime("/var/www/html/Access/images/'$file");

    // Add the file name and last modified time to the array
    $files[$file] = $lastModified;
  }

  // Close the directory
  closedir($dir);

  // Sort the array by last modified time
  asort($files);
  $files=array_reverse($files);
  // Initialize a counter
  $count = 0;

  // Iterate through the sorted array
  foreach ($files as $file => $lastModified) {
    // Display the image
    echo "<img src='/var/www/Access/images/'$file'>";

    // Increment the counter
    $count++;

    // Stop displaying images after the fourth one
    if ($count == 2) break;
  }
?>`
``
```

Comment: `'` single quotation before or after the `$file` variable is redundant `"/var/www/Access/images/'$file"` change to `"/var/www/Access/images/$file"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser can not recognize path except the root of web server.

for example if `/var/www/project/` is your source containg `index.php` that web server load it , browser can read data only in this directory and subdirectory such `/var/www/project/access/images/img.png`

to set `src` attribute of `<img>` you can accomplish this using:

- absoulte path :  `https://example.com/access/images/img.png`
- relative path : `access/images/img.png`

I hope this works

Comment: Thanks for enhancing my knowledge and for code correction.Its working  successfully.

Comment: you're welcome :) please accept the answer and vot it up to other developer use it